# libgdx load 3d model with .g3db is too slow

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I am loading a lot of 3d models in the libgdx .g3db format (29 models), but my phone (NoteII) takes 40 seconds to load and start the game. It is not normal. How to do it faster? I need help! SOS!

For example：

```
 AssetManager assets = new  AssetManager();
 assets.load("data/xxx1.g3db",Model.class);
 assets.load("data/xxx2.g3db",Model.class);
 assets.load("data/xxx3.g3db",Model.class);
                      .
                      .
                      .
 assets.load("data/xxx29.g3db",Model.class);
```

How do you load.
Please help me. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your models are probably too big. How much memory do they use?

Answer (score 1):

Lower the poly on the models. AssetManager is loading them into the memory therefor has to phrase the file. The more poly, the more lines it reads. Just my take on it. I'm actually doing the exact same thing and I'm down to about 15 seconds.